# Angular validator doesnt work when text is inserted into textarea

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, angular-validator

The child component *e-notes-p-quick-phrases-list* has a mat-grid-list that when the user clicks on, can then click an Insert button that inserts that text into the textarea "*notes*" in the parent component.

However, even though it successfully Inserts it, the form is still considered invalid since the user has not typed in the textarea.

How can I get the form to detect that text was inserted into the textarea and change the validator to be true?

I cant seem to find anything about this when I search.

**HTML (parent)**:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save({ methodName: 'setV', visit: $event })">
    <mat-form-field class="bordered">
        <textarea matInput formControlName="notes" value="{{visit.ENotes}}"
                              placeholder="E Notes" rows="5" id="DropHere"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
                
    <div>
        <e-notes-p-quick-phrases-list [vId]='this.vId' (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></e-notes-p-quick-phrases-list>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TS (parent)**:

```
createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'pD': [this.selectPValue, Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidatorsLibrary.autocompleteSelect(this.issues)])],
      'sD': [this.selectSValue, AutocompleteValidator.selectNotRequired(this.issues)],
      'notes': [this.v.ENotes, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],

    });
    this.onPageLoad();

  }
```

I also tried adding an on-focus to the textarea but it is not getting triggered:

HTML:

```
<textarea matInput formControlName="notes" value="{{v.ENotes}}"
                          placeholder="E Notes" rows="5" id="DropHere" on-focus="onChanges()"></textarea>
```

TS:

```
onChanges() {
    
      this.form.get('notes').valueChanges
          .subscribe(pd => {
              this.form.get('notes').markAsTouched;
          });
      
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you should use value="{{visit.ENotes}}" remove it. (and set the value on your form this.form.get('notes').setValue(somevalue);). And what does that onChanges method do? Just start listening to your form changes in your OnInit.

Comment: @user3791775 Thanks! Im not sure I understand specifically what you mean by "start listening to your form change in your OnInit" -- I know the OnInit method, but what are you saying to add to it? The problem is that its only detecting if a user Types in the textarea, but its not detecting when text is inserted from a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200895/angular-validator-doesnt-work-when-text-is-inserted-into-textarea#comment131006726_74200895), remove the `value="{{visit.ENotes}}"`. You should not bind the value to something while also providing a form control directive. Instead, call setValue on your form control in the event handler for  `newItemEvent`. Also remember to call `updateValueAndValidity` In your `addItem` method do like so:

**(TS) Parent:**

```
addItem(newItemEvent: ??): void {
  this.form.get('notes').setValue(newItemEvent.ENotes);
  this.form.get('notes').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

For the purpose of subscribing and listening to form changes, the [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) method is better suited than [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges). OnChanges is triggered whenever there are changes made to `@Input` properties of your component. If your parent  component receives inputs, your OnChanges method will re-run whenever these change and subscribe to the form once more.

I know the question relates to a non working validator, but I could not help to notice that there is no button triggering a submit action on the form. I believe you need a `<button type="submit">` within the form tag.